# How to Send Custom push Notification after a Pass has been updated in apple wallet?

Tags: c#, .net, postman, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to send notification on Apple Wallet after an Apple Wallet card has been added.

I tried following method:

Method - Post
Url  - https://gateway.push.apple.com/3/device/fe4fb6e8bd7041a24ca9c7f37df35ceaedc7a250d11e1247097742347625b2d1

Body -

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello"
    }
}
```

I need to send notification for iOS when the person adds a card.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, Apple Wallet itself does not send push notifications that appear as alerts in the Notification Center for pass updates. However, it does use silent push notifications to notify the device that an update is available for a Wallet pass. Here's how it works:

Silent Notifications for Pass Updates: When you update a pass on your server and want the changes to reflect in the user's Apple Wallet, you send a silent push notification to the user's device using the Apple Push Notification service (APN). This notification does not appear as an alert in the Notification Center. Instead, it silently informs the Wallet app that there is an update available for a specific pass.

Wallet App Fetches the Update: Upon receiving this silent notification, the Wallet app on the user's device will contact your server to download the updated pass. The updated pass then replaces the old one in the user's Apple Wallet.

In summary, while you can use silent push notifications to trigger an update of an Apple Wallet pass, these will not result in visible alerts or messages appearing on the user's device. The purpose of these silent notifications is simply to ensure that the pass in the user's Wallet is up-to-date.

But when you change something in pass when user ask to update it, user recieve push notification. Just change something in you pass.json. For example:

```
    "backFields": [
      {
        "key": "back",
        "label": "Back",
        "value": "2345",
        "changeMessage": "Changed to %@"
      }
    ]
```

And user will see message "Changed to 2345" in case if previously this value was not 2345